# How do I put big brackets under different parts of an equation to attach text labels?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

How do I put big brackets under different parts of an equation so that I can write, e.g., text specific to these parts?

For example:

```
f =  x^3 +  2
    |___|  |__| 
      |     |
   text 1  text 2
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787837/how-to-put-a-big-bracket-under-different-parts-of-a-equation-so-that-i-could-wri?noredirect=1) was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: The question mentions "brackets", while the answers below provide "braces".  For a bracket approach, there is this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161459/how-to-link-two-terms-in-math-mode

Answer (score 267):

Since the text used in `\underbrace` (or `\overbrace`) is typically set in a different font size to not distract further from the equation, it is preferable to use [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)'s `\text` macro.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}% Loads amsmath
\begin{document}
\[
  f(x) = 
    \underbrace{(x + 2)^3}_\text{text 1} + 
    \bigl(
      \mathrlap{\overbrace{\phantom{(c - 2d)}}^{\text{text 2}}}
      (c - 
      \mathrlap{\underbrace{\phantom{2d) + (3e}}_{\text{text 3}}}
      2d) +
      \overbrace{(3e - 4f)}^{\text{text 4}}
    \bigr) + 
    \overbrace{(x - 3)}^\text{text 5}
\]
\end{document}
```

The difficult overlapping braces uses `math` over`lap`s from [`mathtools`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools). It follows a process of setting the `\over`-/`\underbrace` text first with a `\phantom` base, after which the base (or part thereof) is re-set. However, if those aren't needed, using `amsmath` only would suffice for usage of `\text`.

There are a number of ways of achieving the overlapping output. Another method of overlapping braces is discussed in section **63.2 Overlapping braces** of the [`mathmode` document](http://mirrors.ctan.org/obsolete/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf).

Comment: Would you still use `\text` if you wanted to include math?  e.g., instead of "text 1" I want to have something like $g(x)$.  (Also, congrats on your 1000th answer.  Awesome work!)

Comment: @MikeWierzbicki: Thanks - 1000! No, if you use math, then you would not use `\text`, since math will automatically size to the appropriate font size. The switching of mode (from math to text) causes default settings to be invoked, setting text in `\normalsize` rather than `\scriptsize`. [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)'s `\text` *chooses* the appropriate text font size via `\mathchoice`.

Comment: Perhaps the single most useful answer on this entire forum

Comment: Good, answer, but how can I add equations since `\text` is used.

Comment: @GoingMyWay: You're going to have to *show* what you're after, since it's not clear from your comment.

Comment: I mean if you want to add equations, use \underbrace{}_{\mathrm{}}` instead of `\text`

Comment: @GoingMyWay: You're going to have to be a bit more verbose than that. Whether you use `\mathrm` or `\text`, it should not make a difference, unless the annotation is wider than its base. At that point, you would probably use `\mathclap` to hide the horizontal length.

Comment: Any ideas on how to insert a breakline inside the `\text{}` object under the `\underbrace`?

Comment: @Tropilio: You can use a `tabular`, or `array`, or `substack`.

Answer (score 45):

What you want is

```
f = \underbrace{x^3}_\textrm{text 1} + \underbrace{2}_\textrm{text 2}
```

Comment: NB syntax for overbraces, `\overbrace{x^2}^\text{over}`

Comment: For those who might be interested, with Beamer, the subcript `\textrm{..}` needs to be enclosed with braces: `\underbrace{x^3}_` **`{`** `\textrm{text 1}` **`}`**  otherwise it seems that there is a compilation error.

Answer (score 4):

You would find it out in the [mathmode manual](http://tug.ctan.org/obsolete/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf) or [symbols manual](http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf).

Comment: Please provide hyperlinks for the manuals. Not everybody may know where to find them. (I've added them for you.) Also you should consider providing more information. The poster may not know what to look for.

Comment: The link to mathmode manual gives me a 404.