# Subscript Bracket

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to put a big bracket under different parts of a equation so that I could write e.g. a text specific to that part in the equation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44834/how-to-put-a-big-bracket-under-different-parts-of-a-equation-so-that-i-could-wri)

Does anyone know how to code the subscript squiggle thing?
It looks kind of like

```
$f_a + f_a + f_a$   
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  
       f_n
```

I personally don't know how to explain it. It's used in math. If you have a set of numbers and you put the squiggle underneath them and in the center below the squiggle you put like `f_n` denoting that the expression above the squiggle is the same as `f_n`.

Comment: It's called an `\underbrace`.

Comment: See [How to put a big bracket under different parts of a equation so that I could write e.g. a text specific to that part in the equation?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44834/5764) Does this answer your question?

Comment: @Werner Yes, buy how do you insert the text to go under it?

Comment: For example like so: `$\underbrace{f(x)}_{\textit{function}}$`

Comment: @AnthonyPeter In your case: `$\underbrace{f_a + f_a + f_a}_{f_n}$`

Comment: @ChristianR.: Using `\textit` in the argument of `\underbrace` will not scale to the usual math script fontsize. `\text` (from [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)) is better.

Comment: What you gotta do, is print the document out, and using a texta, do it by hand.