# nested comments for equation

Tags: comments

I would like to know how to make a nested comments (see figure) for a equation.

Kind Regards
S.L.

[image: nested comments]

Comment: Would this help? http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/170872/34618

Comment: Please see revision for improved syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapted from my answer at [How to link two terms in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161459/how-to-link-two-terms-in-math-mode), though I had to make some changes.  First, you helped me discover a bug there (which I fixed), when the label was wider than the underset material.  But in addition, I had to introduce a new dimension.

EDITED to improve syntax, but the basic macro is `\ubar{left term}{middle stuff}{right term}{label}`.  In order to nest them, I now provide `\addlevel` and `\subtractlevel`.

To change the nest level (bracket depth), pre-emptively invoke `\addlevel` prior to the invocation (can be done more than once).  Then, within the middle stuff, you can invoke `\subtractlevel` to reduce the bracket depth.  In these two macros, I merely play with the strut height.

However, if you wish to adapt `\addlevel` and `\subtractlevel` to alter any of the dimensions, those at your disposal are:

`\rldp`  the vertical underset of the horizontal bar

`\rlht` the height of the vertical struts below the math

`\rlwd` the rule width, and

`\rlstub` the height of the bottom (central) rule leading to the undertext

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,graphicx,amsmath}
\stackMath
\newlength\rldp
\rldp1.3ex
\newlength\rlht
\rlht.8ex
\newlength\rlstub
\rlstub.8ex
\newlength\rlwd
\rlwd.8pt
\setstackgap{L}{\rldp}
\def\uvbarR#1{%
  \def\stackalignment{r}\def\stacktype{S}\stackunder[-\rlwd]{%
    \def\stackalignment{c}\def\stacktype{L}\stackunder{#1}{\rule{\rlwd}{\rlht}}%
  }{\setbox0\hbox{$#1$}\rule{.5\wd0}{\rlwd}}%
}
\def\uvbarL#1{%
  \def\stackalignment{l}\def\stacktype{S}\stackunder[-\rlwd]{%
    \def\stackalignment{c}\def\stacktype{L}\stackunder{#1}{\rule{\rlwd}{\rlht}}%
  }{\setbox0\hbox{$#1$}\rule{.5\wd0}{\rlwd}}%
}
\newlength\tmplen
\def\uvbar#1#2{%
  \def\stacktype{S}\def\useanchorwidth{T}\def\stackalignment{c}\stackunder[0pt]{%
    \def\stacktype{L}\setbox0\hbox{${}#1{}$}%
    \stackunder[\rldp]{{}#1{}}{\rule{\wd0}{\rlwd}}%
  }{\def\stacktype{S}\stackunder[1pt]{\rule{\rlwd}{\rlstub}}{\scriptscriptstyle#2}}%
}
\newcommand\ubar[4]{\uvbarR{#1}\uvbar{#2}{#4}\uvbarL{#3}}
\newcommand\addlevel[1][.9\baselineskip]{%
  \addtolength\rlht{#1}%
  \addtolength\rldp{#1}%
}
\newcommand\subtractlevel[1][.9\baselineskip]{%
  \addtolength\rlht{-#1}%
  \addtolength\rldp{-#1}%
}

\begin{document}
\[\addlevel
a\ubar{b}
{
  \subtractlevel
  \ubar{}{c}{}{\scalebox{.3}{inner}}
  d
}
{e}{\text{outer}}
f + ghick = lmn\]

\[\addlevel\addlevel\ubar
{}
{\subtractlevel\subtractlevel \ubar{a}{^2 + b}{^2}
  {\text{sides}} = \addlevel \ubar{}{c^2}{}{\text{\makebox[3ex][r]{hypotenuse}}}}
{\,\,}
{\text{The Pythagorean Theorem}}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. The code defiantly helps me a lot. Have a nice day :).