# Gathering underbraces

Tags: math-mode, equations

this is my first question in this website. I have to say that it is being very useful for me to visit this site to learn how LaTeX works, so congratulations.

So, the question is, how can I do this? I would like the solution not in tikz because I have never used it. I'm looking for something like a macro or similar. This has to be in equation environment.
[image: joining underbrace]

Thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on my answer at [How to link two terms in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161459/how-to-link-two-terms-in-math-mode/161473#161473), use

`\ubar{left}{middle}{right}{undertext}`

where each term is taken in math mode, including the `undertext`. 
The parameters `\rldp`, `\rlht`, `\rlwd`, and `\rlbr` can be altered to affect the appearance.

`\rldp` is the depth of the primary horizontal underbar

`\rlht` is the height of the vertical struts, both above and below the primary horizontal underbar.

`\rlwd` is the width (thickness) of the rule

`\rlbr` is the height of the secondary vertical rules, which gird the actual math terms.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\stackMath
\def\rldp{1.4ex}
\def\rlht{.8ex}
\def\rlwd{.8pt}
\def\rlbr{2pt}
\setstackgap{L}{\rldp}
\def\uvbarR#1{%
  \def\stackalignment{r}\def\stacktype{S}\stackunder[-\rlwd]{%
    \def\stackalignment{c}\def\stacktype{L}\stackunder{\ubr{#1}}{\rule{\rlwd}{\rlht}}%
  }{\setbox0\hbox{$#1$}\rule{.5\wd0}{\rlwd}}%
}
\def\uvbarL#1{%
  \def\stackalignment{l}\def\stacktype{S}\stackunder[-\rlwd]{%
    \def\stackalignment{c}\def\stacktype{L}\stackunder{\ubr{#1}}{\rule{\rlwd}{\rlht}}%
  }{\setbox0\hbox{$#1$}\rule{.5\wd0}{\rlwd}}%
}
\def\uvbar#1#2{%
  \def\stacktype{S}\def\stackalignment{c}\def\useanchorwidth{T}\stackunder[0pt]{%
    \def\stacktype{L}\setbox0\hbox{${}#1{}$}%
    \stackunder[\rldp]{{}#1{}}{\rule{\wd0}{\rlwd}}%
  }{\def\stacktype{S}\stackunder[1pt]{\rule{\rlwd}{\rlht}}{\scriptscriptstyle#2}}%
}
\def\ubr#1{\setbox2=\hbox{$#1$}\stackunder[\dimexpr\rldp-\rlht\relax]{#1}{%
  \llap{\rule{\rlwd}{\rlbr}}\rule{\wd2}{\rlwd}\rlap{\rule{\rlwd}{\rlbr}}}}
\newcommand\ubar[4]{\uvbarR{#1} \uvbar{#2}{#4} \uvbarL{#3}}
\begin{document}
$\ubar{ax}{+ by +}{cz}{h} =d$
\end{document}
```

[image]

As egreg suggests, thinning out the lines through the use of `\rlwd` may be desirable.  Here it is with `\rlwd` set to 0.4pt.

[image]

Comment: Nice, but the lines are definitely too thick.

Comment: @egreg That's why `\rlwd` is a settable parameter.  Perhaps I'll change it.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an option using `\underbrace`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newlength{\lwidth}
\newlength{\rwidth}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  \underbrace{\mathstrut zabc}{} + defg + \underbrace{\mathstrut hijklm} &= n \\[-4\jot]
  \settowidth{\lwidth}{zabc}% Left \underbrace width
  \settowidth{\rwidth}{hijklm}% Right \underbrace width
  \underbrace{\hspace{.6\lwidth} \phantom{{} + defg + {}}\hspace{.6\rwidth}}_{opqr}
  \hspace{.4\rwidth}% Due to right-alignment in align
  \mkern 6mu% Adjustment for missing =
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

The left and right underbrace content length is stored in `\lwidth` and `\rwidth` and used for spacing purposes within the lower `\underbrace`. Minor adjustments are required here and there to position things.

`\mathstrut` forces math content without descenders to have the same depth.

Answer (score 0):

Not perfectly but close to:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

    \begin{equation*}
        \begin{aligned}
            &\underbracket{ax} +  by + \underbracket{cz} = d \\[-14pt]
            &\hphantom{a\!}%
            \underbracket{\hphantom{a+ by+ c}}
        \end{aligned} 
    \end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Good luck

[image]