# How to insert curly brackets in equation but to indicate what a member of that equation stands for?

Tags: brackets

It's simplier to show what I'd like to do[image: here]

Comment: Welcome. Are you looking for `\underbrace`?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. Thanks a lot.
Do I look new at Latex so much? ahaha

Comment: You also have the variant: `\underbracket` (defined in `mathtools`).

Comment: Related: [How to put a big bracket under different parts of a equation so that I could write e.g. a text specific to that part in the equation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44834/134144)