# Put brackets under an equation

Tags: equations

How can I put brackets under a certain equation like this?

[image: here]

This is not a duplicate of [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44834/how-do-i-put-big-brackets-under-different-parts-of-an-equation-to-attach-text-la) because I've tried the solution and this is what I get:

[image: get]

This is my code:

```latex
\[\underbrace{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+...+\sqrt{2}}}}_\text{$n$ nested square roots}} = 2\cos({\frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}}})\]
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please convert your snippet into a complete minimal working example (MWE) including the document class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to `TeX.SE`... You almost did, just a small change need to get your output, to keep subscript for the `underbrace` will meet the requirement, modified `MWE` is:

```
\[
\underbrace{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+...+\sqrt{2}}}}}_{\text{$n$
nested square roots}} = 2\cos\left({\frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}}}\right)
\]
```

PS: I've introduce `\left` and `\right` to increase the bracket size to cover the `fraction` size...

Comment: Thank you! I was also going to google to get bigger bracket but you also solved this haha.